# Failing Typescript imports in unit tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

I am developing a React application using TypeScript and am currently integrating unit tests with Mocha as a test runner.  This has worked reasonably well so far, but I have hit a roadblock where I can use either...

```
import * as Tether from 'react-tether';
```

and my tests will build and run.  The app build fails however, with;

```
 "JSX element type 'Tether' does not have any construct or call signatures."
```

Alternatively, I use:

```
import Tether from 'react-tether';
```

Now the app builds and runs fine, but my tests fail with the error:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

Which implies that the import has produce null.  I have checked react-tether source, and it is using a default export, so I would have thought the second import style would be correct/preferred?

Some information on how the app and tests are built may be helpful:

The project build process uses Webpack with ts-loader first, and babel-loader second.  I have left the JSX compilation to babel, so the tsconfig.json is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "es6",
        "baseUrl": "app/",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./types"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "allowJs": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "dom", 
            "es7"
        ],
        "types": [
            "mocha",
            "chai"
        ]
    }
}
```

For running tests I am using the following script:

```
TS_NODE_PROJECT=test.tsconfig.json NODE_PATH=app mocha --require build-scripts/test-dom --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register"
```

This gets ts-node to compile the files, but using a different tsconfig so that jsx is not preserved.  The test.tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "baseUrl": "app/",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./types"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es7"
        ],
        "types": [
            "mocha",
            "chai"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you find any solution? (I'm working on that....)

Comment: I ended up switching to using Karma on top of Mocha so that I could build my test bundles with webpack.  Then I could use the same .tsconfig for both test and normal builds.  Never came to any conclusion about why this was happening.